# How to make sbt-native-packager refrain from putting my resources into a jar file?

Tags: scala, classpath, sbt-native-packager

I'm using the [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) plugin to generate a start script for my application, which is very convenient as this plugin generates the correct classpath specification with all my library dependencies.  I am not distributing this applictaion, therefore I'm not packaging the entire thing into one tarball.  I just use the `lib` directory generated by sbt-native-packager that contains all the jar-files on which my project depends, both third-party libraries as well as the jar-file that contains my own class and resource files.

In my project's `src/main/resources` directory I have files that I want to be able to edit without having to use sbt-native-packager to regenerate the entire installation, for example configuration files.  This is difficult because those files are zipped up in the jar file with all my classes.

Question: how can I tell sbt-native-packager not to put my resource files into a jar-file, while still generating the start-script with the correct classpath for those resource files to be located and read by my application as they are now from within the jar file?  If this means leaving all my class files out of a jar file that is fine, as long as the files from `src/main/resources` remain as files that I can change without re-invoking `sbt stage` and as long as the start-script works.

Comment: I believe that you are trying to achieve is the default behavior of sbt-start-script https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script#about-this-plugin-sbt-start-script

Comment: @Jhonny Everson That may be, but it was the `README` for that project that led me to sbt-native-packager.  The first thing it says (under a very large heading) is that it may be replaced by sbt-native-packager, which makes it sound as if it's a bad idea to adopt it now since the developer expects to stop maintaining it.  It also describes sbt-native-packager as being "more general," which suggests that anything that plugin can do, sbt-native-packager can also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to filter these resources I would suggest to put them into a different directory and add them to the classpath.

Modifying the start script generated by sbt-native-packager is a bit cumbersome as the class `com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaAppBashScript` that is generating the classpath is prefixing all paths with `$lib_dir/`. The cleanest approach would probably be to provide your own implementation and use that to generate the `bashScriptDefines`.

A simpler but hacky way would be to just add the following lines to your `build.sbt`:

```
packageArchetype.java_server

// add your config files to the classpath for running inside sbt
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(sourceDirectory.value/"main"/"config")

// map all files in src/main/config to config in the packaged app
mappings in Universal ++= {
  val configDir = sourceDirectory.value/"main"/"config"
  for {
    file <- (configDir ** AllPassFilter).get
    relative <- file.relativeTo(configDir.getParentFile)
    mapping = file -> relative.getPath
  } yield mapping
}

scriptClasspath ~= (cp => "../config" +: cp)
```

This will prepend `$lib_dir/../config` to your start script's classpath. If your app has to run on Windows you will have to provide similar settings for the `batScriptDefines`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions; I'll try them out.  Question: is there any way just to prevent my files (config/resource & bytecode/class) from being zipped into a jar? Then the classpath would stay the same and I could could leave the start-script as is?

Comment: Actually that would mean that the classpath changes (in the packaged app) as the classes would end up in a directory in a different location. Another option would be to add a system property by e.g. setting `bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava -Dmy.config.dir="$(realpath "${app_home}/../config")""""` and read that in your program but that would need some extra work to make the `run` command work nicely with that.

Comment: "that would mean that the classpath changes (in the packaged app) as the classes would end up in a directory in a different location."

I would be interested in knowing how to do that: leaving all my files (config plus class files) out of any jar file.

Comment: @Moritz `scriptClasspath ~= (cp => "../config" +: cp)` adds the folder to the classpath, why do you need the `mappings in Universal...` part then? I mean, I understand that it is mapping, but why do you need it in the context of Adam's quetion?